How to extract still frame as image file from a video on macOS?

I want to capture some still frames from a video on macOS.
I can of course pause the video at desired frame and "grab screenshot to the selected part of screen" using ⌘ Command ⇧ Shift 4, but I'm looking for a more automated, accurate and easier way that doesn't require me to manually select the screen area of each frame.

Is there a better way?

I found two ways (references: search results from discussions.apple.com)

[Better] Specific to VLC Media Player

Pause video at desired frame and from Menu bar select Video > Snapshot.
A vlcsnap-xxxx.png file of the current frame will get stored in ~/Desktop



Applicable to any video player application
Use macOS's screenshot feature

Pause video at desired frame and hit ⌘ Command ⇧ Shift 5 to open screenshot overlay and in the hovering bar select 2nd option: Capture Selected Window [ ref-1 , ref-2 ]
after this click on your video-player window to grab screenshot of it's contents.





In case it helps your workflow, in VLC, the Video -> Snapshot menu command works without needing to pause the video. I sometimes use Command-Option-s repeatedly in quick succession to get the optimal framing, unfuzziness, etc, from the vid. There is usually a noticeable delay the first time, while the video keeps on moving, so I either use the command early to get it going, or do it once, wait for the confirmation, then back the video up a few secs and start key-pressing as fast a I care to when the part I want to grab from resumes. See Settings -> Video to set name, format, & where they land.
